# expression databinding(<%# %>) syntax work without a datasource

Tags: asp.net

Whether expression databinding(<%# %>) syntax work without a datasource?

such as:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt" Text='<% #GetValue() %>'/>
```

Comment: That notation won't work, but <%= GetValue() %> should

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That syntax should work without a data source if you call `this.DataBind()` during page initialization.